# Display database HTML value via DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, domdocument

The database has the value: `This is a test.<br><h1>this is also a test.</h1>This is a test.<br>this is a test.<br>`

Using mysql the value is given by: `$DBval['test']`.
the row settings are:

Type = LONGTEXT
    Collation = UTF8_general_ci

> ```
>   $doc = new DOMDocument();
>
>   $test = $doc->createElement("div");
>   $doc->appendChild($test);
>
>   $test_value = $doc->createElement("p", $DBval['test']);
>   $test->appendChild($test_value);
>
>   echo $doc->saveXML();
> ```

result:

> `"This is a test.<br><h1>this is also a test.</h1>This is a test.<br>this is a test.<br>"`

The result is written in plain text and weirdly enough in double quotes.

I just want the result to be written in HTML like this:

> This is a test.
>
> ## this is also a test.
>
> This is a
>   test.
> this is a test.

Comment: Have you tried just `echo $test_value;` to see if variable contents is escaped or `appendChild` method escapes it?

Comment: $test_value; would be an instance of DOMElement and echoing it will most likely triggre an error.

Comment: @Louis Loudog Trottier - my mistake, I meant `echo $DBval['test'];`

Comment: If we didn't do mistakes, SO would not exist :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a few reason why ths will not work (at least as expected)

1. If you have 'malformed' html you will need to use saveHTML() instead of saveXML().
2. Since your string is already containting some html tag you will need to do an loadHTML(); insert it
3. You can echo ONLY the element by passing the DOMElement to the saveHTML($text_value) so you don't echo all the document.
4. Take into account that domDocuemnt will emcapsulate any 'free-floating' text into a `<p>` tag. In this case of text only node you shall use ->createTextNode() Instead.

Now, here is the tricky part: You can do:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();     
  $doc->loadHTML($DBval['test']);  
  echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

But if you want to actually 'import' html into another DOMElement you do need to IMPORT it. Here a function i used (addapted for your case and commented for explaination)

```
  //For a valid html5 DOCTYPE declaration
  //$doc = new DOMDocument();
  $dom = new DOMImplementation;
  $doc = $dom->createDocument(null, 'html', $dom->createDocumentType('html'));

  //To keep thing tidy
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->formatOutput = true;
  $doc->encoding = 'utf8';

  //Creates your test div
  $test = $doc->createElement("div");
  $doc->appendChild($test);

  /** HERE STARTS THE MAGIC */
  $tempDoc= new DOMDocument; //Create a temp Doc to import the new html 
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //This prevent some garbage warning.

  //Prevent encoding garbage on import, change accordingly to your setup
  $htmlToImport = mb_convert_encoding($DBval['test'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf8');
  //Load your Html into the temp document
  //As commented, we'll encapsulate the html in a span to prevent DOM to automaticly add the 'p' tag
  $tempDoc->loadHTML('<span>'.$htmlToImport.'</span>');
  //$tempDoc->loadHTML($htmlToImport); //@REMOVED: was adding 'p' tag

  //Restore Garbage Warning report
  libxml_clear_errors();  
  libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

  //Get the htl to import now sotred in the body of the temp document
  $bodyToImport = $tempDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

  //Import all those new childs to your div
  foreach($bodyToImport->childNodes as $node){
    $test->appendChild($doc->importNode($node->cloneNode(true),true));
  }    

  /** All this to replace these 2 lines :( 
  $test_value = $doc->createElement("p", $DBval['test']);
  $test->appendChild($test_value);
  */

  //echo $doc->saveXML();
  echo $doc->saveHTML(); //echo all the document
  //echo $doc->saveHTML($test); //echo only the test 'div'
```

I've used the term 'garbage' beacuse it is mainely error you can ignore, but while you dev, you might wat to take a look at those error.

I know this looks overkill but it's the only way i managed to work with any HTML, charset and make it work in a clean way.

Really hope this helps. DOM can be tricky but it has the abiity to keep thing structured if used properly.

Comment: Thanks @Louis Loudog Trottier, for the detailed answer, the only thing that if i try to run this code the echo looks like this(in html). `<p>This is a test.<br></p>
<h1>this is also a test.</h1>This is a test.<br>this is a test.<br>`. 
the <p> element stops at the <h1> and doesn't continue for the text after <h1>has ended, the <h1> tag stops <p> from continuing(it would be nice if the <h1> is inside the <p> element). I'm already happy using just the <br> for styling if the <h1> issn't fixable.

Comment: If you just emcapsulate your original string with something like an span it should sholve your problem. As mention, DOMDocument have tendencies to add p tags to hold text. Unfortunately i don't know how to prevent this behavior, i need to work around it. Probably that simply `$tempDoc->loadHTML('<span>'.$htmlToImport.'</span>');` would do the trick for you. Will edit answer to refelct comment.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, i just have to abandon the `<p>` tag and change the CSS styling to `<span>` instead, it has the same result. Weird that there is a different outcome when changing `<span>` to `<p>` (that it stops when hitting the `<h1>`). Thanks again! hope this help others to  with little DOMDocument knowledge.

Comment: I think what is happening is, It sees a text that is not encapsulated, so he add the opening `<p>` tag, but since a `<h1>` is not permitted (as well-formed html) inside a `<p>` tag it has to close it before the `<h1>`.  Using the `<span>` workaround, the whole text and child elements are already encapsulated inside a (now imported and well formed html) instance of DOMElement (and not textNode) (the span, containing everything else). All assumption based on my experiences.